# Broadcast Reveiver not being called from Alarm Manager

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've searched the archives and still can't resolve my issue.

I'm trying to take an user input in seconds that will call the broadcast receiver to create a toast message and vibrate the phone. However, the broadcast receiver is never called and I can't figure it out. My code is below.

Thanks!

```
package com.example.cs984x.alrm;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText inputSeconds = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            int inputTime = Integer.parseInt(inputSeconds.getText().toString());
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The alarm will go off in " + inputTime + " seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
            myIntent.setAction("com.example.cs984x.alrm.vibrate");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,   System.currentTimeMillis()+(inputTime*1000), pendingIntent);


        }
    });
}
}
```

Broadcast Receiver Class:

```
package com.example.cs984x.alrm;

import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.content.Context.ALARM_SERVICE;


public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Toast.makeText(context, "Your time is up", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Vibrator v;
    v= (Vibrator)context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(2000);

}

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.cs984x.alrm">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" >
</uses-permission>

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>


    <receiver

    android:name=".MyReceiver" android:process=":remote"

    android:enabled="true">

  <intent-filter>

        <action android:name="com.example.cs984x.alrm.vibrate" />

    </intent-filter>

</receiver>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? I've been digging for the past 3 hours and can't find out what's wrong. I seems like it should work.

Comment: The `<receiver>` element in the manifest needs to go between the `<application>` tags, just like your `<activity>` element.

Comment: That did it... man I wasted a lot of time on that little screw up. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Add action to intent:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyReceiver.class);
myIntent.setAction("YourPackageName.YourAction");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent =PendingIntent.getBroadcast(MainActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);
```

in AndroidManifest:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="YourPackageName.YourAction" />
            </intent-filter>
```

Comment: I still couldn't get it to work. I'm not sure if I added the package correctly. I edited the code above with the setAction and manifest changes.